# How to programmatically enumerate an enum type?

Tags: enums, typescript

Say I have a TypeScript `enum`, `MyEnum`, as follows:

```
enum MyEnum {
    First,
    Second,
    Third
}
```

What would be the best way in TypeScript 0.9.5 to produce an array of the `enum` values? Example:

```
var choices: MyEnum[]; // or Array<MyEnum>
choices = MyEnum.GetValues(); // plans for this?
choices = EnumEx.GetValues(MyEnum); // or, how to roll my own?
```

Answer (score 198, accepted):

This is the JavaScript output of that enum:

```js
var MyEnum;
(function (MyEnum) {
    MyEnum[MyEnum["First"] = 0] = "First";
    MyEnum[MyEnum["Second"] = 1] = "Second";
    MyEnum[MyEnum["Third"] = 2] = "Third";
})(MyEnum || (MyEnum = {}));
```

Which is an object like this:

```
{
    "0": "First",
    "1": "Second",
    "2": "Third",
    "First": 0,
    "Second": 1,
    "Third": 2
}
```

**Enum Members with String Values**

TypeScript 2.4 added the ability for enums to possibly have string enum member values. So it's possible to end up with an enum that look like the following:

```
enum MyEnum {
    First = "First",
    Second = 2,
    Other = "Second"
}

// compiles to
var MyEnum;
(function (MyEnum) {
    MyEnum["First"] = "First";
    MyEnum[MyEnum["Second"] = 2] = "Second";
    MyEnum["Other"] = "Second";
})(MyEnum || (MyEnum = {}));
```

**Getting Member Names**

We can look at the example immediately above to try to figure out how to get the enum members:

```
{
    "2": "Second",
    "First": "First",
    "Second": 2,
    "Other": "Second"
}
```

Here's what I came up with:

```
const e = MyEnum as any;
const names = Object.keys(e).filter(k => 
    typeof e[k] === "number"
    || e[k] === k
    || e[e[k]]?.toString() !== k
);
```

**Member Values**

Once, we have the names, we can loop over them to get the corresponding value by doing:

```
const values = names.map(k => MyEnum[k]);
```

**Extension Class**

I think the best way to do this is to create your own functions (ex. `EnumEx.getNames(MyEnum)`). You can't add a function to an enum.

```
class EnumEx {
    private constructor() {
    }

    static getNamesAndValues(e: any) {
        return EnumEx.getNames(e).map(n => ({ name: n, value: e[n] as string | number }));
    }

    static getNames(e: any) {
        return Object.keys(e).filter(k => 
            typeof e[k] === "number"
            || e[k] === k
            || e[e[k]]?.toString() !== k
        );
    }

    static getValues(e: any) {
        return EnumEx.getNames(e).map(n => e[n] as string | number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Curiously (because many people have upvoted this answer), I can't get this to work in the TS Playground: https://shorturl.me/jJ8G2t Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: @Peter I updated the answer to include information about string enums. Also, you'll want to use a `for of` statement instead of a `for in`

Answer (score 31):

With [TypeScript >= 2.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html) you can define string enums:

```
enum Color {
  RED = 'Red',
  ORANGE = 'Orange',
  YELLOW = 'Yellow',
  GREEN = 'Green',
  BLUE = 'Blue',
  INDIGO = 'Indigo',
  VIOLET = 'Violet'
}
```

JavaScript ES5 output:

```
var Color;
(function (Color) {
    Color["RED"] = "Red";
    Color["ORANGE"] = "Orange";
    Color["YELLOW"] = "Yellow";
    Color["GREEN"] = "Green";
    Color["BLUE"] = "Blue";
    Color["INDIGO"] = "Indigo";
    Color["VIOLET"] = "Violet";
})(Color || (Color = {}));
```

Which is an object like this:

```
const Color = {
  "RED": "Red",
  "ORANGE": "Orange",
  "YELLOW": "Yellow",
  "GREEN": "Green",
  "BLUE": "Blue",
  "INDIGO": "Indigo",
  "VIOLET": "Violet"
}
```

Thus, in the case of string enums, no need to filter things,
`Object.keys(Color)` and `Object.values(Color)` are enough:

```
const colorKeys = Object.keys(Color) as (keyof typeof Color)[];
console.log('colorKeys =', colorKeys);
// ["RED", "ORANGE", "YELLOW", "GREEN", "BLUE", "INDIGO", "VIOLET"]

const colorValues = Object.values(Color);
console.log('colorValues =', colorValues);
// ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Indigo", "Violet"]

colorKeys.map(colorKey => {
  console.log(`color key = ${colorKey}, value = ${Color[colorKey]}`);
});
/*
color key = RED, value = Red
color key = ORANGE, value = Orange
color key = YELLOW, value = Yellow
color key = GREEN, value = Green
color key = BLUE, value = Blue
color key = INDIGO, value = Indigo
color key = VIOLET, value = Violet
*/
```

See online [example on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJygbwFBSgJQKIAiUAvFAOQ7AAmZANFlAPI4CCAcgOJ4nmPICGIAObA6DAJp4AMlMYB1HmXHAESAO5jsHfHjaKOyYKE1QAQlICq3UmVMIwo+tgCSbAs46NFzkFQCWQnAmAGrOjFJ4ACqKwX6IwAAuZBgAvhgYAMZwIADOCVBZSMgA0sAAnjk8jABGAFbAGQkAdADW5TkAFPBFAJRQ-JUdbWVwAGZQCWUADsBjsIgoPQDaALoA3JnZOfFNSEIdZIUopRUkdAULJe09GwD0t1BLAET4BE+0UE-M7Fzvn5IyeR-J7aPC6YHmKzA1zuTzA0LhKJPFbpLK5fJHZDBfj2YCVUg1eqNJoANxxDk63UWGzR2wQwF2cH2h0u2Nx+POmLZFJuGHujxe1GBfEEImBylUcDUwIMRhAENx0N8ATg8Li9ISyNRlxOOSaEH4Uw6mJOJAAfOgGLSdnsOgADTFQYY8AAkaBN5RSHzJuNdaCpyCWHrKKxSdt5KV5twAVJsik7yjxXt7ycAk9Q4ygE2UqqxOHgU76CQJhMBM6hnaQAbI5IWHDwJepy9meKDdHW06RZaBm5WzJYC1AffXSHYHL3E6QYR5GB2eD5-IEJznSAiIpE56v1YkMNHbhggA)

Comment: This has the error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof Color'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof Color'.`

Comment: @Jonas I've fixed it with a cast: `Object.keys(Color) as (keyof typeof Color)[]`

Answer (score 10):

There is no concept of RTTI (runtime type information) in TypeScript (think: reflection) so in order to do this, knowledge of the transpiled JavaScript is required. So, assuming TypeScript 0.95:

```
enum MyEnum {
    First, Second, Third
}
```

becomes:

```
var MyEnum;
(function(MyEnum) {
    MyEnum[MyEnum["First"] = 0] = "First";
    MyEnum[MyEnum["Second"] = 1] = "Second";
    MyEnum[MyEnum["Third"] = 2] = "Third";
}
```

So, this is modeled as a regular object in javascript, where `MyEnum.0 == "First"` and `MyEnum.First == 0`. So, to enumerate all of the enum names, you need to get all properties that belong to the object and that are also not numbers:

```
for (var prop in MyEnum) {         
    if (MyEnum.hasOwnProperty(prop) &&
        (isNaN(parseInt(prop)))) {
        console.log("name: " + prop);
    }
}
```

Ok, so now I've told you how to do it, I'm allowed to tell you **this is a bad idea**. You're not writing a managed language, so you can't bring these habits. It's still just plain old JavaScript. If I wanted to use a structure in JavaScript to populate some kind of choices list, I would use a plain old array. An enum is not the right choice here, pun intended. The goal of TypeScript is to generate idiomatic, pretty JavaScript. Using enums in this way does not preserve this goal.

Answer (score 9):

You can add functions to get the names and indices of the enum:

```
enum MyEnum {
  First,
  Second,
  Third
}

namespace MyEnum {
  function isIndex(key):boolean {
    const n = ~~Number(key);
    return String(n) === key && n >= 0;
  }

  const _names:string[] = Object
      .keys(MyEnum)
      .filter(key => !isIndex(key));

  const _indices:number[] = Object
      .keys(MyEnum)
      .filter(key => isIndex(key))
      .map(index => Number(index));

  export function names():string[] {
    return _names;
  }

  export function indices():number[] {
    return _indices;
  }
}

console.log("MyEnum names:", MyEnum.names());
// Prints: MyEnum names: ["First", "Second", "Third"]

console.log("MyEnum indices:", MyEnum.indices());
// Prints: MyEnum indices: [0, 1, 2]
```

Note that you *could* just export the `_names` and `_indices` consts rather than exposing them through an exported function, but because the exported members are members of the enum it is arguably clearer to have them as functions so they are not confused with the actual enum members.

It would be nice if TypeScript generated something like this automatically for all enums.

Answer (score 5):

I used the solution proposed by David Sherret and wrote an npm library you can use named `enum-values`...

[Git: enum-values](https://github.com/slavik57/enum-values)

```
// Suppose we have an enum
enum SomeEnum {
  VALUE1,
  VALUE2,
  VALUE3
}

// names will be equal to: ['VALUE1', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE3']
var names = EnumValues.getNames(SomeEnum);

// values will be equal to: [0, 1, 2]
var values = EnumValues.getValues(SomeEnum);
```

Answer (score 3):

A one-liner to get a list of entries (key-value objects/pairs):

```
Object.keys(MyEnum).filter(a=>a.match(/^\D/)).map(name=>({name, value: MyEnum[name] as number}));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
enum MyEnum {
    First, Second, Third, NUM_OF_ENUMS
}

for(int i = 0; i < MyEnum.NUM_OF_ENUMS; ++i) {
    // do whatever you need to do.
}
```

Comment: This only works if your enum doesn't define any values (it is well packed and incremental). Enum values might be "First = 0x1000" or "PageNotFound = 404" for example. NUM_OF_ENUMS will always be one greater than the largest defined value, so 0x1001 or 405 in my examples.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to associate strings values to your enum these methods don't works. To have a generic function you can do :

```
function listEnum(enumClass) {
    var values = [];
    for (var key in enumClass) {
        values.push(enum[key]);
    }
    values.length = values.length / 2;
    return values;
}
```

It's works because TypeScript will add keys in first step, and values in second step.

In TypeScript it's:

```
var listEnums = <T> (enumClass: any): T[]=> {
    var values: T[] = [];
    for (var key in enumClass) {
        values.push(enumClass[key]);
    }
    values.length = values.length / 2;
    return values;
};

var myEnum: TYPE[] = listEnums<TYPE>(TYPE);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Iterating over an enum

String Enums are best used for this. Here is an example:

```
// This is a string enum
enum MyEnum {
    First = 'First',
    Second = 'Second',
    Third = 'Third',
}

// An enum is a TS concept
// However his MyEnum compiles to JS object:
//  {
//   "First": "First",
//   "Second": "Second",
//   "Third": "Third"
// } 


// Therefore we can get the keys in the following manner:
const keysArray = Object.keys(MyEnum);

for (const key of keysArray) {
    console.log(key)
}
// [LOG]: "First" 
// [LOG]: "Second" 
// [LOG]: "Third"
```

Answer (score 1):

[joe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23899551/741981) just made me realize that is much more easier to rely on the first N numeric keys than making more complex testings:

```
function getEnumMembers(myEnum): string[]
{
    let members = []
    for(let i:number = 0; true; i++) {
        if(myEnum[i] === undefined) break
        members.push(myEnum[i])
    }

    return members
}

enum Colors {
    Red, Green, Blue
}

console.log(getEnumMembers(myEnum))
```

Comment: This is a dangerous assumption because it is possible to define the values assigned to enums and they don't need to be incremental and well packed. It's not uncommon to see bit masks in an enum for example, or perhaps a table of HTML error codes that start at 400.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Answer (score 1):

A type-safe solution could be as follows:

```
enum Color { 
  Blue = 'blue', 
  Green = 'green'
}

enum MoreColor {
    Yellow,
    Red
}

function getEnumValues<T, K extends keyof T>(enumType: T): Array<T[K]> {
  return getEnumKeys<T, K>(enumType).map((x) => enumType[x]);
}

function getEnumKeys<T, K extends keyof T>(enumType: T): Array<K> {
  return Object.keys(enumType)
    .filter((x) => Number.isNaN(Number(x)))
    .map((x) => x as K);
}

// return type is Color[]
const colorValues = getEnumValues(Color); // ["blue", "green"]

// return type is MoreColor[]
const moreColorValues = getEnumValues(MoreColor); // [0, 1]

// return type is Array<"Blue" | "Green">
const colorKeys = getEnumKeys(Color); // ["Blue", "Green"]

// return type is Array<"Yellow" | "Red">
const moreColorKeys = getEnumKeys(MoreColor); // ["Yellow", "Red"]
```

But keep in mind that this solution does not force you to pass just `enum`s to the function.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted Typescript to be able to statically typecheck my switch cases on the list of enum cases to make sure they were exhaustive. Other answers could do this if your enum definition was a number enum, but my specific use case was where they case names didnt match the associated string values.

So I created this generic helper function that will return all the cases of your enum, typed as the enum case, not a string, or a keyof union type. (I use the `never` typing in the switch default case to get a red squiggly in my IDE when the switch case is not exhaustive.)

```js
enum Enum {
    FOO = 'foo',
    BAR = 'bar',
    // BAZ = 'baz',
}

function enumCases<O extends object>(obj: O): Array<NonNullable<O[keyof O]>> {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key, _) => {
    const candidateCase = obj[key as keyof typeof obj];
    if (candidateCase && Number.isNaN(parseInt(key, 10))) {
      acc.push(candidateCase);
    }
    return acc;
  }, Array<NonNullable<O[keyof O]>>());
}

// example usage; try uncommenting the BAZ case of the enum
// to see both static and runtime errors
for (const enumCase of enumCases(Enum)) {
    switch (enumCase) {
        case Enum.FOO:
            console.log('reached case', Enum.FOO);
            break;
        case Enum.BAR:
            console.log('reached case', Enum.BAR);
            break;
        // case Enum.BAZ:
        //     console.log('reached case', Enum.BAZ);
        //     break;
        default:
            const unhandled: never = enumCase;
            throw new Error(`your Enum has changed! need to update the switch case to include ${unhandled}`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for nodejs:

```
const { isNumber } = require('util');

Object.values(EnumObject)
      .filter(val => isNumber(val))
      .map(val => {
         // do your stuff
      })
```