# Enum as Parameter in TypeScript

Tags: enums, typescript

Isn't it possible to set the type of a parameter to an Enum?      Like this:

```
private getRandomElementOfEnum(e : enum):string{
    var length:number = Object.keys(e).length;
    return e[Math.floor((Math.random() * length)+1)];
}
```

Following error is thrown:

> Argument expression expected.(1135)

With `any` obviously everything is alright:

```
private getRandomElementOfEnum(e : any):string{
    var length:number = Object.keys(e).length;
    return e[Math.floor((Math.random() * length)+1)];
}
```

Is there a possibility or a little workaround to define an enum as a parameter?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `e: MyEnumType`? Or do you want to accept any kind of enum. What good would that do? You can also do `e: MyEnum|MyOtherEnum|MyThirdEnum` .

Comment: Related (but possibly out-dated): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293063/how-to-programmatically-enumerate-an-enum-type-in-typescript-0-9-5?rq=1

Comment: every enum should be possible, so i can get ah random element of every enum by calling this function.

Comment: your seconds solution @Thilo works but isn't very handy, it should work for every enum.

Comment: @Thilo, No.  MyEnum as a type offers its value type.  If you want the enum itself to be passed, you need to think of it as an object.

Comment: It's as good question. I think the best you can do in TypeScript is (referring to OP's first code snippet) to use `object` as the type for `e`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's not possible to ensure the parameter is an enum, because enumerations in TS don't inherit from a common ancestor or interface.

TypeScript brings static analysis. Your code uses dynamic programming with `Object.keys` and `e[dynamicKey]`. For dynamic codes, the type `any` is convenient.

Your code is buggy: `length()` doesn't exists, `e[Math.floor((Math.random() * length)+1)]` returns a string or an integer, and [the enumeration values can be manually set](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#basic-types-enum)…

Here is a suggestion:

```
function getRandomElementOfEnum<E>(e: any): E {
    var keys = Object.keys(e),
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length),
        k = keys[index];
    if (typeof e[k] === 'number')
        return <any>e[k];
    return <any>parseInt(k, 10);
}

function display(a: Color) {
    console.log(a);
}

enum Color { Blue, Green };
display(getRandomElementOfEnum<Color>(Color));
```

Ideally, the parameter type `any` should be replaced by `typeof E` but the compiler (TS 1.5) can't understand this syntax.

Comment: hehe, my code was actualy buggy, I realized it about 10min later, forgot to change the code here..

Comment: It is possible, with some extra `enum`-like types passing through a filter. But if it talks like `enum` and works like `enum`, why differ? Just `<Enum extends Record<string, string | number>>(e: Enum) => { ... };`

Answer (score 33):

You can do better than `any`:

```
enum E1 {
    A, B, C
}
enum E2 {
    X, Y, Z
}

function getRandomElementOfEnum(e: { [s: number]: string }): number {
    /* insert working implementation here */
    return undefined;
}

// OK
var x: E1 = getRandomElementOfEnum(E1);
// Error
var y: E2 = getRandomElementOfEnum(window);
// Error
var z: string = getRandomElementOfEnum(E2);
```

Comment: The compiler assumes that `E1` matches to the type `{ [s: number]: string }`, but is it perennial? The object `E1` contains string keys.

Comment: Number indexers don't constrain non-number key types

Comment: The compiler compiles this to:
`function getRandomElementOfEnum(e) {
    /* insert working implementation here */
    return undefined;
}`

Comment: Note that even though TS does reverse mapping and one would probably think of these enums as "key "A" of E1 having value 0", `[s: string]: number` doesn't work.

Comment: Sort of works, but far from perfect.

Comment: No, its bad, it does not capture type information, its just as good as `any`

Answer (score 22):

Summing up the previous answers with some new syntax - a generic typesafe function, which works with numeric enums as well as string enums:

```js
function getRandomElementOfEnum<T extends {[key: number]: string | number}>(e: T): T[keyof T] {
  const keys = Object.keys(e);

  const randomKeyIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length);
  const randomKey = keys[randomKeyIndex];

  // Numeric enums members also get a reverse mapping from enum values to enum names.
  // So, if a key is a number, actually it's a value of a numeric enum.
  // see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings
  const randomKeyNumber = Number(randomKey);
  return isNaN(randomKeyNumber)
    ? e[randomKey as keyof T]
    : randomKeyNumber as unknown as T[keyof T];
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, perfect solution, thank you so much

Comment: The only minor problem is, it's not restricted to enums.  One can pass `{ p1: true, p2: { f: 8}}` to it as well.

Comment: The safest type I could come up with is `Record<string | number, string> | Record<string, number>`.  It still doesn't catch { p1: 5, p2, "f" }, but also flushes out some unexpected inputs.

Answer (score 18):

I agree with @Tarh. Enums in TypeScript are just Javascript objects without a common interface or prototype (and if they are `const enum`, then they are not even objects), so you cannot restrict types to "any enum".

The closest I could get is something like the following:

```
enum E1 {
    A, B, C
}
enum E2 {
    X, Y, Z
}

// make up your own interface to match TypeScript enums
// as closely as possible (not perfect, though)
interface Enum {
    [id: number]: string
}

function getRandomElementOfEnum(e: Enum): string {
   let length = Object.keys(e).length / 2;
   return e[Math.floor((Math.random() * length))];
}
```

This works for all enums (without custom initializers), but it would also accept other arrays as input (and then fail because the method body relies on the very specific key structure that TypeScript enums have).

So unless you have a real need for such a "generic" function, make typesafe functions for the individual enum types (or a union type like `E1|E2|E3`) that you actually need.

And if you do have this need (and this might very well be an X-Y-problem that can be solved in a better, completely different way given more context), use `any`, because you have left typesafe territory anyway.

Comment: I haven't tested this theory but I'm pretty sure your implementation doesn't support `enum E3 { X = 4, Y, Z }`

Comment: it should be `interface Enum {[key: number]: string | number}` actually

Answer (score 11):

Another possible option not mentioned above is using the actual values. This is however possible only when you know all the options. This, in my opinion is definitely better than any.

```
    doSomething(a: string, b: 'this'|'can'|'work'): void {
     //do something
    }
```

Comment: Yeah of course better than any, but this solution is pretty hard in maintenance. Everytime we edit the values of the enum we would need to remember where we used it and also refactor these parameters.

Comment: you saved me <3

Comment: Actually you can use this as the type for b: `b: keyof typeof MyEnumType`

Comment: @PabloMartínez Thats the best for this question. Post as an answer

Comment: @Ayyappa: It depends on the type of enum. If the enum is a string map it's not going to work. Like `enum MyEnum { A = "admin", U = "user"} ` unfortunately won't work.

Comment: Simple and clean answer

Answer (score 6):

May be this trick will fit:

```
enum AbstractEnum { // put somewhere in hidden scope
}

private getRandomElementOfEnum(e: typeof AbstractEnum) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I like this, and you can further strengthen the typing of the function by defining it as `private getRandomElementOfEnum<T extends typeof AbstractEnum>(e: T): T[keyof T] {...}`.

Answer (score 6):

Tested on TypeScript 3.9.7

#### Solution

```
type EnumTypeString<TEnum extends string> =
    { [key in string]: TEnum | string; }

type EnumTypeNumber<TEnum extends number> =
    { [key in string]: TEnum | number; }
    | { [key in number]: string; }

type EnumType<TEnum extends string | number> =
    (TEnum extends string ? EnumTypeString<TEnum> : never)
    | (TEnum extends number ? EnumTypeNumber<TEnum> : never)

type EnumOf<TEnumType> = TEnumType extends EnumType<infer U>
    ? U
    : never
```

#### Usage

EnumType:

```
function forEachEnum<TEnum extends string | number>(
    enumType: EnumType<TEnum>,
    callback: (value: TEnum, key: string) => boolean|void,
) {
    for (let key in enumType) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(enumType, key) && isNaN(Number(key))) {
            const value = enumType[key] as any
            if (callback(value, key)) {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EnumOf:

```
function forEachEnum2<TEnumType>(
    enumType: TEnumType,
    callback: (value: EnumOf<TEnumType>, key: string) => boolean|void,
) {
    for (let key in enumType) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(enumType, key) && isNaN(Number(key))) {
            const value = enumType[key] as any
            if (callback(value, key)) {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Tests

```
enum EnumAsString {
    Value1 = 'value 1',
    Value2 = 'value 2',
}

enum EnumAsNumber {
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2,
}

// Error
let sn: EnumType<string> = EnumAsNumber

// Correct
let ns: EnumType<number> = EnumAsString // I have not found a solution for the error here
let nn: EnumType<number> = EnumAsNumber
let Nn: EnumType<EnumAsNumber> = EnumAsNumber
let ss: EnumType<string> = EnumAsString
let Ss: EnumType<EnumAsString> = EnumAsString

forEachEnum(EnumAsString, value => {
    let e: EnumAsString = value
    let s: string = value
    let n: number = value // Error
})

forEachEnum(EnumAsNumber, value => {
    let e: EnumAsNumber = value
    let s: string = value // Error
    let n: number = value
})

forEachEnum2(EnumAsString, value => {
    let e: EnumAsString = value
    let s: string = value
    let n: number = value // Error
})

forEachEnum2(EnumAsNumber, value => {
    let e: EnumAsNumber = value
    let s: string = value // Error
    let n: number = value
})
```

Comment: could you maybe provide some simple explanation? would be useful for not so experienced other users instead of only code

Answer (score 3):

@selinathat's solution is great only if you have few types. but what if we have more ? for example :

```
doSomething(a: string, b: 'this'|'can'|'work'|'test1'|'test2'|'test3'): void {
 //do something
}
```

its pretty ugly hah !?
i prefer to use **keyof** :

```
interface Items {
    'this',
    'can',
    'work',
    'test1',
    'test2',
    'test3',
}

doSomething(a: string, b: keyof Items): void {
 //do something
}
```

Comment: Check my comment in his answer:
`b: keyof typeof MyEnumType`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that allows passing an enum with a typechecked value of that enum using a generic. It's really a response to a slightly different question here that was marked as a duplicate: [Typescript how to pass enum as Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199509/typescript-how-to-pass-enum-as-parameter)

```js
enum Color {
    blue,
};
enum Car {
    cadillac,
};
enum Shape {
    square,
}

type SupportedEnums = typeof Color | typeof Car;

type InvertTypeOf<T> = T extends typeof Color ? Color :
    T extends typeof Car ? Car : never;

function getText<T extends SupportedEnums>(enumValue: InvertTypeOf<T>, typeEnum: T) string | undefined {
  if (typeEnum[enumValue]) {
    return `${enumValue}(${typeEnum[enumValue]})`;
  }
}

console.log(getText(Car.cadillac, Car)); // 0(cadillac)
console.log(getText(0, Color)); // 0(red)
console.log(getText(4, Color)); // undefined

// @ts-expect-error Color is not Car
console.log(getText(Color.blue, Car));

// @ts-expect-error Car is not a Color
console.log(getText(Car.toyota, Color));

// @ts-expect-error  Shape is not in SupportedEnums
console.log(getText(5, Shape));

// @ts-expect-error  Shape is not in SupportedEnums
console.log(getText(Shape.square, Shape));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem, and i did this

```js
  private getOptionsFromEnum(OptionEnum: Record<string, string>): Array<SelectOption> {
    return Object.keys(OptionEnum).map((value) => {
      return {
        name: OptionEnum[value],
        value,
      } as SelectOption;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a helper type to accept any enum as a paramaeter, then you can handle whatever you need next with `Object` or by calling an index of the Enum.

```
type Enum = Record<string | number, string | number>
```

Now use it to accept any enum as parameter:

```
function enumValues<T extends Enum>(enum: T, filter?: "string"): string[];
function enumValues<T extends Enum>(enum: T, filter?: "number"): number[];
function enumValues<T extends Enum>(enum: T, filter?: undefined): (string|number)[];
function enumValues<T extends Enum>(enum: T, filter?: "string" | "number") {
  return Object.values(enum).filter(x => !filter || typeof x === filter);
}

enum color {
  red,
  green,
  blue
}

console.log(enumValues(color,"string"));
// output ['red','green','blue']

console.log(enumValues(color,"number"));
// output [0,1,2]
```