# TypeScript function accept argument value from an enum

Tags: enums, typescript

Code below,the parameter `gender` is `enum type`,the value must be one of `["male","female"]`,but I want to use it simply like this `judgeGender("male")`,how can I make it?

```
function judgeGender(gender){
    //......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is accept a String and [check that it exists in the Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18112157/2039244), like so:

```
enum Gender {Male, Female};

function validGender(c: String) {
    if(enumHasValue(Gender, c)) {
        document.write(`valid gender: ${c}`);
    } else {
        document.write(`invalid gender: ${c}`);
    }
}

function enumHasValue(e, v) {
    for (var enumMember in e) {
        if (enumMember === v) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

validGender("Female"); // => "valid gender: Female"
document.write("<br/>");
validGender("Alien"); // => "invalid gender: Alien"
```

Try this example out in the [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground) (copy and paste it in and press *Run*).

Comment: Your suggestion is very helpfull,thanks for your answer :)

Comment: If I wanna to make a type check to the parameter `e` of the function `enumHasValue`,just like `function enumHasValue(e:??,v:string)`,how to make it?

Comment: [Take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774874/enum-as-parameter-in-typescript).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to parse the `gender` parameter, like this:

```
function parseGender(value : Gender | number | string) {
  var gender;
  if (value === Number(value)) {
    gender = <Gender>value;
  }
  else if (value === String(value)) {
    if (<string>value in Gender) {
      gender = Gender[value];
    }
  }

  if (!gender) throw new TypeError("The parameter gender is incorrect");
  return gender;
}
```

And then you can use it inside your function:

```
function judgeGender(gender : Gender | number | string) {
  var g = parseGender(gender);

  // do whatever you want with g
}
```

Comment: Wow,it's a neat solution,but as your function: `parseGender(0)=>0;parseGender("male")=>0` ,then I change `gender = Gender[value];` to `gender = <Type>value;`;so `parseGender(0)=>0;parseGender("male")=>"male"`. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which values your function can receive.

```
type Male = "male";
type Female = "female";

enum Gender {
    Male = Male,
    Female = Female
}

function judgeGender(gender: Gender | Male | Female) {
    //......
}

judgeGender(Gender.Male);
judgeGender("male");
```