# Typescript how to pass enum as Parameter

Tags: typescript, enums

How can i pass enum type defined as parameter. Check at my usage on the bottom of the following picture.

[image: Code sample]

Comment: please paste code not images of your code. It helps people trying to help you.

Comment: Thanks the link you provide contains the best solution for my case

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an easy way to say "only support enums" like you want. You have some options though. You can keep adding enums you want to support:

```
enum Color {};
enum Car {};
type SupportedEnums = typeof Color | typeof Car;
function getText(enumValue: number, typeEnum: SupportedEnums) {
    retrun `${enumValue}(${typeEnum[enumValue]})`;
}
```

Or, instead of maintaining `SupportedEnums`, just use `any` type.

====

Original answer:

You can refer to the type by using `typeof`:

```
getText(enumValue: number, typeEnum: typeof Color): string {
    return typeEnum[enumValue];
}
```

Comment: This won't work in my case since this getText function will be use with 2 different enum type. See my usage case at the bottom of the image. I'm looking for a generic function to pass any type of enum.

Comment: This also doesn't work for me. I get this error:
`TS2693: 'Color' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Comment: I posted an update back to the post this one was marked as a duplicate of. IMO an improvement on the type checking at the expense of more code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774874/enum-as-parameter-in-typescript/62857364#62857364

Answer (score 0):

For any `enum`, use `any`.

```
function getText(enumValue: number, typeEnum: any): string;
```

To restrict the possible enums, use the union type.

```
function getText(enumValue: number, typeEnum: typeof Car | typeof Color): string;
```

Comment: Thanks this solution is working

Comment: This works, but I really wish there were a better way. I don't quite understand why we can't make a function like:
`function getText<E>(enumValue: number, typeEnum: E): string;`

Comment: Use `unknown` instead of `any`