# Typescript Function Accepting Any Enum

Tags: typescript

I'd like to create a function that accepts any Enum. For example

```
function AcceptOne(one: Enumerator) {}
```

With an enum

```
enum Animal {
    Dog = 'Dog'
}
```

And then call

```
AcceptOne(Animal.Dog);
```

But I get the error

> Argument of type 'Animal' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Enumerator'

Comment: [`Enumerator`](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_scripthost_d_.enumerator.html) and enum are two very different things.

Comment: Could you please state a scenario where you can accept "any" enum?

Comment: Enums are unsafe. DOn't do this under any circumstances. Take a look on this example https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwdgrgtgBAgmAllAhgGxgb2DGARAewHMAaYAX2FElgDECCATLHGABURDMuADMIwAYwAuiAmHiDBIAA7CA8mBAAKcSABcMGgCMQAJwCULXIPEBnAmhAA6NMVVKDFKnCmyFS5QmTprhIgYA3MCu0nKKKvRM1hwgQUA . Also enums are mutable

Answer (score 0):

"It's not possible to ensure the parameter is an enum, because enumerations in TS don't inherit from a common ancestor or interface.", taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774874/enum-as-parameter-in-typescript).

Assuming your enums will only have string values, you may as well just change the `one` type to `string` and then any of these enums value will work:

```
enum Animal {
    Dog = 'Dog'
}

enum Food {
    Pie = 'Pie'
}

function AcceptOne(one: string) {
  console.log(one)
}

AcceptOne(Animal.Dog);
AcceptOne(Food.Pie);
```

[Sandbox link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=21&pln=2&pc=1#code/FAUwdgrgtgBAgmAllAhgGxgb2DXMAiA9gOYwC8MA5EcZcAL7CiSwBihhAJljngAqIQ5KgJB1GwAGYQwAYwAuiQmHizZIAA7yA8mBAAKZSABcMAM7yATojDEAlD1yzlZwmhAA6NCUN67DJjg1TR09fQRkdA8aOwBuYCD1LV0Ddi4PUTigA)