# JSON array object passed from AngularJs , received as null in ASP.NET Web API controller

Tags: angularjs, webapi

I am trying to post a JSON array (stuanswer) from AngularJs to my ASP.NET web api controller. However I get it as null in the controller (`List<StuAnswerViewModel> answer`).
I ensured browser debugging, to check if json array has data in it and it has.
`ID` column is autoincremented in the database, hence I am not passing the value. Even when I tried passing ID from json, still getting null.

I am not able to understand what is missing. Can you please help?
THE JSON REQUEST header taken from network tab is

Request URL: http://localhost:1487/api/test/saveans
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 937
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cookie: repository=%7B%22loggedUser%22%3A%7B%22username%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22authdata%22%3A%22dW5kZWZpbmVkOnVuZGVmaW5lZA%3D%3D%22%2C%22Userid%22%3A1%2C%22Medium%22%3A%221%22%7D%7D
Host: localhost:1487
Origin: http://localhost:1487
Referer: http://localhost:1487/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36
{0: {QuesID: 1, StudentId: 2, TestId: 1, GivenAnswer: 1, TestTakenDate: "01-01-01"},…}
0: {QuesID: 1, StudentId: 2, TestId: 1, GivenAnswer: 1, TestTakenDate: "01-01-01"}
1: {QuesID: 1, StudentId: 2, TestId: 1, GivenAnswer: 1, TestTakenDate: "01-01-01"}
2: {QuesID: 1, StudentId: 2, TestId: 1, GivenAnswer: 1, TestTakenDate: "01-01-01"}
3: {QuesID: 1, StudentId: 2, TestId: 1, GivenAnswer: 1, TestTakenDate: "01-01-01"}
4: {QuesID: 1, StudentId: 2, TestId: 1, GivenAnswer: 1, TestTakenDate: "01-01-01"}
5: {QuesID: 1, StudentId: 2, TestId: 1, GivenAnswer: 1, TestTakenDate: "01-01-01"}
6: {QuesID: 1, StudentId: 2, TestId: 1, GivenAnswer: 1, TestTakenDate: "01-01-01"}
7: {QuesID: 1, StudentId: 2, TestId: 1, GivenAnswer: 1, TestTakenDate: "01-01-01"}
8: {QuesID: 1, StudentId: 2, TestId: 1, GivenAnswer: 1, TestTakenDate: "01-01-01"}
9: {QuesID: 1, StudentId: 2, TestId: 1, GivenAnswer: 1, TestTakenDate: "01-01-01"}
10: {QuesID: 1, StudentId: 2, TestId: 1, GivenAnswer: 1, TestTakenDate: "01-01-01"}
The request headers copied from the browser are

GET /Scripts/spa/Student/quesCtrl.js HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1487
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: script
Referer: http://localhost:1487/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("saveans")]
public HttpResponseMessage SaveAnswer(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromBody] List<StuAnswerViewModel> answer)
{
    return CreateHttpResponse(request, () =>
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        }
}

public class StuAnswer
{
    public StuAnswer()
    {
        // Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime TestTakenDate { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public int QuesID { get; set; }
    public int GivenAnswer { get; set; }
}

function test()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < qLength; i++) 
    {
        $scope.stuanswer[i] = 
            {
                QuesID: 1,
                StudentId: 2,
                TestId:1,
                GivenAnswer: 1,
                TestTakenDate: '01-01-01'
            }               
     }

     apiService.post('/api/test/saveans', $scope.stuanswer,
            saveansSucceded,
            saveansFailed);
     }
```

Comment: Can you do the following? Open your website in the browser - In the browser press F12 - Go to the **network** tab - trigger the request - select the request - copy the request body and paste it in the question too. If you know how to use postman or a similar tool, try to post the json string and see if this also is a problem?

Comment: I have included the request headers taken from the browser @Pieterjan

Comment: Sorry you posted the wrong request. We need the **request body** of **saveans**

Comment: i have posted the json request , sorry i cud nt format it

Comment: Okay it seems that angularjs takes `stuanswer` as an object instead of an array.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37648825/8941307) should solve your problem. `let answers = []; Object.keys($scope.stuanswer).forEach((index, answer) => answers.push(answer); apiService.post('/api/test/saveans', answers, ...);`

Comment: Perfect.. got it.. thank you @Pieterjan, you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public IActionResult SaveAnswer( [FromBody] List<StuAnswer> answer)
    {
       return Ok("sucess");
    }
```

Comment: this is web api controller, hence I am not using ActionResult. hope it makes sense

Comment: @ArunVijai Try and let me know the result