# String enum like type in typescript

Tags: javascript, enums, typescript, iterable

I am looking for a string enum that can be iterated.

What I tried so far:

String union types:

```
type t = "p1" | "p2" | "p3"
```

Problem: Can't be iterated

Enum:

```
enum t { p1, p2, p3 }
```

Problem: can't have string enum

Object:

```
const t = {p1: "p1", p2: "p2", p3: "p3"}
```

Problem: can't strongly type a variable that should be "p1", "p2", or "p3"

I could use an object and string union types or an enum and a map but I end up repeating myself a lot. What is the proper way to get a string enum that you can iterate in typescript?

Comment: This is javascript, it has strings, numbers, objects as types. It's not a statically typed language either. So you may want to rethink the problem you're trying to solve here and whether strong typing is what you need.

Comment: @CallumLinington I tagged it typescript too. Typescript is a typed superset of javascript

Comment: Well that changes everything... see [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/enums.html)

Comment: You're running into a limitation of Javascript, which doesn't have a representation for typing, or enums. See the link that David Sherret posted for how to represent in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need the value to be a string. Note that you can get the enum value from its name using `t.p1` or `t["p1"]`, and you can get it's name from its enum value using `t[0]`.

For example:

```
enum t { p1, p2, p3 }

function foo(x : t) {
    console.log(`value: ${x}, name: "${t[x]}"`);
}
foo(t.p1);      // value: 0, name: "p1"
foo(t["p1"]);   // value: 0, name: "p1"
```

But if you really need to accept string values, you could always do this (yes, this would get pretty redundant after a while):

```
function foo(x : t | "p1" | "p2" | "p3") {
    if (typeof x == "string") x = t[x];
    console.log(`value: ${x}, name:"${t[x]}"`);
}

foo("p1");      // value: 0, name: "p1"
```

Comment: Can you iterate over an enum?

Comment: @2426021684 Sure, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21294925/1715579).