# Get enum values by enum name string

Tags: typescript, enums

In Typescript I get a `string` variable that contains the name of my defined `enum`.

How can I now get all values of this enum?

Comment: you could use reflection, something like this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338610/dynamically-loading-a-typescript-class-reflection-for-typescript. Anyway I would first think if that is the right way to go or you can access it in a "normal" way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typescript enum:

```
enum MyEnum {
    First, Second
}
```

is transpiled to JavaScript object:

```
var MyEnum;
(function (MyEnum) {
    MyEnum[MyEnum["First"] = 0] = "First";
    MyEnum[MyEnum["Second"] = 1] = "Second";
})(MyEnum || (MyEnum = {}));
```

You can get `enum` instance from `window["EnumName"]`:

```
const MyEnumInstance = window["MyEnum"];
```

Next you can get enum member values with:

```
const enumMemberValues: number[] = Object.keys(MyEnumInstance)
        .map((k: any) => MyEnumInstance[k])
        .filter((v: any) => typeof v === 'number').map(Number);
```

And enum member names with:

```
const enumMemberNames: string[] = Object.keys(MyEnumInstance)
        .map((k: any) => MyEnumInstance[k])
        .filter((v: any) => typeof v === 'string');
```

See also [How to programmatically enumerate an enum type in Typescript 0.9.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293063/how-to-programmatically-enumerate-an-enum-type-in-typescript-0-9-5)

Comment: Window[enumname] did not work, maybe because we use namespaces. But "eval(enumname)" did work.

Comment: Is there a React friendly alternative to this?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the `window` approach that the other answers offer, you could do the following:

```
enum SomeEnum { A, B }

let enumValues:Array<string>= [];

for(let value in SomeEnum) {
    if(typeof SomeEnum[value] === 'number') {
        enumValues.push(value);
    }
}

enumValues.forEach(v=> console.log(v))
//A
//B
```

Comment: If we had the instance of the enum then it is easy to get the list of values. The questions was how do we get the enum instance from the string value.